# Working directory

Tags: c++, working-directory

How do I make the working directory the "debug directory"  but not through the properties, but through the code?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows, visual studio. It doesn't have to be the debug directory, but it has to be relative to the solution directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chdir ("Debug");
```

That's what I use for Windows apps.

Obviously, the directory "Debug" would be inside the current working directory.
To go up a level:

```
chdir("..");
```

Or to make a directory:

```
mkdir("Debug");
```

Incidentally, if you need to know where your working directory currently is, use something like:

```
char workingDir [_MAX_PATH];
_getcwd( workingDir, _MAX_PATH );
```

Comment: That assumes that the working directory used to be one level up from the "debug" directory. I've also seen cases where you would need "bin/Debug" or "debug/bin".

Answer (score 1):

In your own code, there's no such thing as a "debug directory". That's a property of your debugger or IDE.